# Showing custom markers with unique data in Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to achieve this (ctto):
[image]

The first plan I was thinking is to create a custom info window. But then I realized that `mapView.selectedMarker = marker` can only select and show 1 info window at a time.

So my second plan was to create custom markers with the integers inside it. Just like in the picture above. I just know how to change the default marker, but putting unique data to it for each marker, that I don't know.

Please help thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display multiple info windows for multiple markers without tapping it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487733/is-it-possible-to-display-multiple-info-windows-for-multiple-markers-without-tap)

Answer (score 0):

the [GMSMarker has a property called icon view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker.html#ab16a10487ace24ac36e96eea7efb77c7) . You can use that one to build the custom marker icon with your custom data. As an example embedding an UILabel in it.