# Custom infoWindow Google Maps IOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, infowindow

I customized a infoWindow, but this shows a infowindow default in the background. Is there a way to hide the infoWindow background? or that I'm doing wrong.

[image]

**The code is:**

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
        if let infoView = UIView.viewFromNibName("MarkerInfoView") as? MarkerInfoView {
            infoView.lblTitle.text =  "Title" //marker.title
            infoView.lblDescription.text = "Description"
            infoView.lblDescription.numberOfLines = 0
            infoView.lblDescription.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
            infoView.lblDescription.sizeToFit()
            return infoView
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in your nib file, where you do custom look for your info window, set top nib view background color to `clear color`

Answer (score 0):

Set your custom view as the marker image instead of the info window.

Convert your custom view into image and set it as marker image.

That will solve your purpose.

Comment: And How Could do it? Any idea is welcome to add the title and description to the image

Comment: You can refer to the code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487733/is-it-possible-to-display-multiple-info-windows-for-multiple-markers-without-tap/39490480?noredirect=1#comment66339836_39490480

Comment: Just create your own custom view by defining the frame as required and set the title and description as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement this method and return your custom view.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you don't have

```
    marker.title = "something"
```

anywhere in your code. Then the default will always show unless you use

```
     func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    <#code#>
    }
```

to set your infoWindow properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `customInfoWindow`, then you don't have to access  `GMSMarker()` properties like `marker.snippet` and `marker.title`

Even if you use them by mistake in your code, then you need to return an empty view in delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
   return UIView()
}
```